# Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't recognize Kindle Paperwhite

Tags: 18.04, usb, kindle

I started using Ubuntu(18.04) recently and to this moment I am very satisfied.
I am facing this problem with the Kindle Paperwhite not being recognized by the usb.
I have tested other devices and worked normally, only the Kindle is not recognized. it even turns on the charging light near the Power button.

I ran some commands in the terminal to try to identify if Ubuntu is recognizing the device and apparently this is not happening.

Among these commands one of them was `ls /dev/ | grep sd`

The output of the command was the same whether the device was connected or disconnected.

I tested it on other USB ports.

---

OUTPUTS with Kindle connected

```
$ sudo apt list *mtp* | grep installed 
WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
gmtp/bionic,now 1.3.10-1 amd64 [installed]
libmtp-common/bionic,bionic,now 1.1.13-1 all [installed]
libmtp-runtime/bionic,now 1.1.13-1 amd64 [installed]
libmtp9/bionic,now 1.1.13-1 amd64 [installed]
libnet-smtp-ssl-perl/bionic,bionic,now 1.04-1 all [installed]
mtp-tools/bionic,now 1.1.13-1 amd64 [installed]
```

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c07f Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ lsblk
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
loop0                     7:0    0  34,8M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1122
loop1                     7:1    0 140,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/78
loop2                     7:2    0  14,5M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop3                     7:3    0 128,5M  1 loop  /snap/vscode/77
loop4                     7:4    0    91M  1 loop  /snap/core/6405
loop5                     7:5    0   2,3M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop6                     7:6    0 140,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop7                     7:7    0   7,5M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/58
loop8                     7:8    0    13M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop9                     7:9    0  34,6M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop10                    7:10   0  53,7M  1 loop  /snap/core18/719
loop11                    7:11   0   3,7M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
loop12                    7:12   0   174M  1 loop  /snap/spotify/34
loop13                    7:13   0   5,8M  1 loop  /snap/tor/2
loop14                    7:14   0    66M  1 loop  /snap/discord/91
loop15                    7:15   0    91M  1 loop  /snap/core/6350
loop16                    7:16   0   7,5M  1 loop  /snap/canonical-livepatch/54
sda                       8:0    0 223,6G  0 disk  
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2                    8:2    0   732M  0 part  /boot
└─sda3                    8:3    0 222,4G  0 part  
  └─sda3_crypt          253:0    0 222,4G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root   253:1    0 221,4G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 253:2    0   976M  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                       8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sdb1                    8:17   0 931,5G  0 part  /media/pedro/Vault
```

```
$ jmtpfs
No mtp devices found.
```

```
$ dmesg | curl -F c=@- https://ptpb.pw
date: 2019-02-28T19:33:00.232964+00:00
digest: b6f4b200bfc91f41fdfb31e04f100fed679714bf
long: ALb0sgC_yR9B_fsx4E8QD-1nlxS_
short: lxS_
size: 61329
status: created
url: https://ptpb.pw/lxS_
uuid: f104d68c-0a1c-48cc-9817-05146950ba14
```

Comment: `lsusb` or `lsblk` when it is plugged in and not plugged in. I wouldn't expect it to show up as `/dev/sd?`

Comment: You can run `lsusb` to see devices coonnected to the USB bus. Also, just after connecting the Kindle, run `dmesg` and look for messgesg about new usb device.

Comment: Yes, I've tried these commands and I've seen them in other posts here at AskUbuntu. but the output remains the same, does not change whether the Kindle is connected or not.
I have already tried connecting it to other Windows computers and it worked.

Comment: Output lsusb: 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0cf3:0036 Atheros Communications, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c07f Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Comment: @PHFP please edit your original post rather than forcing us to read through your unformatted comment. Also as Soren said `dmesg` will be useful here as well, and rather than paraphrasing "*... remains the same, does not change...*" post the **full** output in your question

Comment: As a last-ditch try, sometimes for reasons not for mortal man to know, devices will connect on one USB port but not on another.

Comment: Can you execute `apt list *mtp* | grep installed` and post the output of that command in your question?  I use 'jmtpfs' to connect to my paperwhite.

Comment: @j-money Thanks for the advice, I just made the changes you suggested.
 The dmesg output is insanely big, have any problems in posting it?

Comment: @CharlesGreen 
I just ran the suggested command and added the output in question.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I tried on other USB ports.

Comment: Please execute 'sudo apt install jmtpfs' - you *might* need to reboot

Comment: @CharlesGreen jmtpfs installed successfully, system rebooted but kindle not recognized.

Comment: `dmesg | curl -F c=@- https://ptpb.pw ` then when it spits out a link, just post it in your question

Comment: @j-money done, output posted

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It was a problem with the JBL USB cable.
From what I realized this cable only serves to recharge devices and not to transfer files.

Comment: Had this issue with "amazon basics" cable too. Tried a generic phone charger cable and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, it can even be the connector which is flawed : tweaking it a bit inside the kindle slot mounted it.